# Opencart using the add cart function [PHP]

Tags: php, arrays, opencart

Having trouble formatting the the options to manually add products to the cart on the back end.

```
$option = "[option] => Array([494] => 1004)";
$this->cart->add(68, 1, $option);
```

This correctly adds the product however the options are ignored. 
I assume I'm formatting the options the $option variable correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know OpenCart API, but you have a wrong syntax. Try to use this:

```
$option = array("option"=>array(494 => 1004));
$this->cart->add(68, 1, $option);
```

Comment: Thanks for correcting the  syntax however sadly no luck!

Comment: Try to use this: 

`$option = array(494 => 1004); $this->cart->add(68, 1, $option);`